# sort data when loop by a calculated column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

someone can help me to sort this table by calculated $changepercentage please.
My table has more than 1000 records and it's uploaded by date order . I tried arsort() , SORT() when it's echo but PHP says it's not an array but a string.
I have tried mysqli_fetch_array() also but no luck.
need your kind help.

clo_prices (table)

```
date        |  name   |   cl_price |
2015-09-15  |  AAA    |    10      |
2015-09-15  |  BAA    |    20      |
2015-09-15  |  ABA    |    30      |
2015-09-16  |  AAA    |    86      |
2015-09-16  |  BAA    |    65      |
2015-09-16  |  ABA    |    33      |
```

price_list (table)

```
date       | name     | volume    | last |
2015-09-15 | AAA      | 6655245   | 56   |
2015-09-15 | ABA      | 5666      | 65   |
2015-09-15 | AAB      | 1333      | 33   |
2015-09-16 | AAA      | 112365    | 56   |
2015-09-16 | ABA      | 23131     | 8    |
2015-09-16 | AAB      | 23330     | 12   |
2015-09-16 | ABB      | 2323122   | 60   |  
2015-09-16 | ACB      | 21222     | 99   |
```

Desired Result

```
date       | company    | closing  | volume    | Change % |
2015-09-16 | AAA        | 56       | 6655245   | 66       |
2015-09-16 | ABA        | 65       | 5666      | 9.7      |
2015-09-16 | ACB        | 69       | 1333      | 7        |
2015-09-16 | AAB        | 33       | 112365    | 3.2      |
```

---

```
$queryTMG = "SELECT price_list.date, price_list.name, price_list.last, price_list.volume,
                    clo_prices.date, clo_prices.name, clo_prices.cl_price                   
                FROM price_list 
                INNER JOIN clo_prices
                ON price_list.name = clo_prices.name 
                WHERE price_list.date= '$dateT' AND 
                      clo_prices.date = '$dateT' 
                ORDER BY cl_price DESC LIMIT 10 ";

$queryPMG = "SELECT price_list.date, price_list.name, price_list.last, price_list.volume, 
                    clo_prices.date, clo_prices.name, clo_prices.cl_price
                FROM price_list 
                INNER JOIN clo_prices
                ON price_list.name = clo_prices.name 
                WHERE price_list.date= '$dateT' AND 
                      clo_prices.date = '$dateP' 
                ORDER BY cl_price DESC LIMIT 10";


$resultTMG = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryTMG) or die (mysqli_error());
$resultPMG = mysqli_query($dbc, $queryPMG) or die (mysqli_error());

echo '<table  cellpadding = 15 border =1>';
echo '<tr> 
        <th>Company</th> 
        <th>Closing Rs.</th> 
        <th>Volume</th> 
        <th>Change %</th> 
        </tr>';

while($rowTMG = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTMG) AND $rowPMG = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultPMG))
{
        echo '<tr> <td>'. $rowTMG['name']. '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $rowTMG['last']. '</td>';
        echo '<td align = "right">'. $volumeTMG = number_format($rowTMG['volume']). '</td>';
        echo '<td align = "right">'.$changeprecentage = 
           number_format((( $rowTMG['cl_price'] - $rowPMG['cl_price'] ) /
                          $rowTMG['cl_price']), 2, '.', '' ). '</td> </tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: First of all you can not add 2 conditions at the same time in expect 2 queries returns same number of results. you can remove those assignments like $volumeTMG = and $changeprecentage = as these are not required

Comment: This is possible in one query. Way faster because the query optimizer can see how to sort the table.

Answer (score 0):

I probably have not quite understood yet how you compute your percentages, because using the data given I get different results, see [my fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52ba1/15)

```
SELECT p.date, p.name, p.last, p.volume,
       d.cl_price+0 prevprice,
       c.cl_price+0 currprice,                  
       100*(c.cl_price-d.cl_price)/c.cl_price perc_change
FROM price_list p
INNER JOIN clo_prices c ON p.name = c.name   -- current prices
                       AND p.date = c.date
INNER JOIN clo_prices d ON p.name = d.name   -- previous prices
                       AND '2015-09-15' = d.date
WHERE p.date= '2015-09-16'
ORDER BY perc_change desc
```

This solution is so far *only* a MySQL `select` statement, since everything *can* be done in a single query. You will probably have to sort out some of the logic or the input data.

For the purpose of the example I assumed that `$dateT` is `'2015-09-16'` and `$dateP` is `'2015-09-15'`.

Comment: thanks very much cars10 , can you explain me what's "d.cl_price" pls

Comment: To be honsest, I don't think that I fully understood your intentions. So my query was just an attempt to show you how you can compare select lines in a single table to each other. `d.cl_price` is the price for a `name` taken from `clo_prices` with `date='2015-09-15'` while `c.cl_price` is a price for the same `name` taken from the same table but for he date `'2015-09-16'`. My percentages do not work out the same as the ones given in your example. But it should be clear from my code how they are calculated. Feel free to modify it to suit your needs!